# Hibernate Search query fetching data from Actual database and not from Elastic DB indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

We are trying to implement the elastic search in our project. Till now we are able to create indexes under ES. But the issue is while retrieval. When we are firing the query to retrieve data, the query is fired on the actual database, instead of ES DB indexes.

***hibernate.cfg***

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager">elasticsearch</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host">http://127.0.0.1:9200</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy">drop-and-create</property>
<property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status">yellow</property>
```

**Code to search:**

```
 Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.current().getSession("");
      fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session.getSession());
      searchFactory = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory();

QueryBuilder titleQB = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(<MyClassHere>.class).get();

    Query query = titleQB.phrase().onField(EMAIL1_EDGE_NGRAM_INDEX).andField(EMAIL1_NGRAM_INDEX)
            .boostedTo(5).sentence(searchTerm.toLowerCase()).createQuery();

    FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, <MyClassHere>.class);
    fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(20);

    List<Bascltj001TO> results = fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    return results;
```

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class MYClass {
    private DBAccessStatus dBAccessStatus;
    private String optname = "";
    private String phone1 = "";
    @Fields({
          @Field(name = "email1", index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES,
        analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "standardAnalyzer")),
          @Field(name = "edgeNGramEmail1", index = Index.YES, store = Store.NO,
        analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "autocompleteEdgeAnalyzer")),
          @Field(name = "nGramEmail1", index = Index.YES, store = Store.NO,
        analyze = Analyze.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "autocompleteNGramAnalyzer"))
        })
    private String email1 = "";
```

**Elastic DB json data**

```
{
        "_index" : "myclass",
        "_type" : "myclass",
        "_id" : "67",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "67",
          "cltseqnum" : 67,
          "email1" : "email@clt.com",
          "edgeNGramEmail1" : "email@clt.com",
          "nGramEmail1" : "email@clt.com"
        }
```

**Analyzer Definitions**

```
@AnalyzerDefs({

        @AnalyzerDef(name = "autocompleteEdgeAnalyzer",

// Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
                tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = KeywordTokenizerFactory.class),

                filters = {
                        // Normalize token text to lowercase, as the user is unlikely to
                        // care about casing when searching for matches
                        @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
                                @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^a-zA-Z0-9\\.])"),
                                @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = " "),
                                @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all") }),
                        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                        @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class),
                        // Index partial words starting at the front, so we can provide
                        // Autocomplete functionality
                        @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
                                @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "3"),
                                @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "50") }) }),

        @AnalyzerDef(name = "autocompleteNGramAnalyzer",

// Split input into tokens according to tokenizer
                tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),

                filters = {
                        // Normalize token text to lowercase, as the user is unlikely to
                        // care about casing when searching for matches
                        @TokenFilterDef(factory = WordDelimiterFilterFactory.class),
                        @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
                        @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class, params = {
                                @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "3"),
                                @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "5") }),
                        @TokenFilterDef(factory = PatternReplaceFilterFactory.class, params = {
                                @Parameter(name = "pattern", value = "([^a-zA-Z0-9\\.])"),
                                @Parameter(name = "replacement", value = " "),
                                @Parameter(name = "replace", value = "all") }) }),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is a full text query so it will be executed on the Elasticsearch cluster - there's no way for Hibernate Search to translate it to a database query.

But... keep in mind that your index does not include all the necessary data to build the entities. Thus, after getting the ids from the Elasticsearch cluster, Hibernate Search will execute a query on your database to get the results as entities.

The only way to avoid that is to use projections to query particular fields of your index but, apart from very specific cases, getting your entities is usually what you want.

Comment: Thank You Guillaume, for the quick response. Could you please elaborate the last point "getting your entities is usually what you want".

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're seeing that it runs a query on *both*. It will certainly not run the query only on the database as it's not possible to run such a fulltext query on the database.

**Default architecture**

The default for a *FullTextQuery* is to run the query on Elasticsearch so to know the primary keys of the objects which match, and then use this list of ids to load the fully managed domain objects from the database.

That's normally what people want, so to make sure you get the latest version of the data and that objects are loaded within the safe scope of a transaction.

Also it allows you to apply changes to the objects, and have these changes applied to both your database and the Elasticsearch cluster when you commit the transaction.

An additional benefit is that you can load all fields from the database, including the ones which are not indexed. So you can skip indexing on all fields which you don't strictly need to run a query - that keeps the indexes light and fast.

**Alternative options**

If for any reason you just want to perform the query on Elasticsearch exclusively, you just have to use projections.

See:

- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_projections

Comment: Projections did the trick. Thank you Sanne and Guillaume. Just as Sanne's answer had the link to the solution, marking it as the answer :)

Below is the updated search query code:
fullTextQuery.setMaxResults(20).setProjection( ElasticsearchProjectionConstants.SCORE, ElasticsearchProjectionConstants.SOURCE );